# Get distinct recent contact column from message table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a message table from where i want to get recent contacts for '**user1**', now the table looks like this:

[image]

The closest sql query i can get is

```
SELECT receiver, sender, time 
from message 
where receiver = 'user1' OR sender = 'user1' 
group by receiver, sender ORDER by time desc
```

which returns

[image]

But it should return result of containing only distinct '**user2**', '**host1**', but the row is duplicated twice

Comment: Replace `receiver, sender` in output and in GROUP BY with `CASE WHEN receiver = 'user1' THEN sender ELSE receiver END`. You'll obtain 2 rows and 2 columns (contact and timestamp). If you need to know does the contact is sender or receiver in the most last row then add one more column with this data, or get receiver and sender in output separately.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expected result achieved through this query as @Akina suggested:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN receiver = 'user1' THEN sender ELSE receiver END AS contact, max(time) AS time 
FROM message 
WHERE receiver = 'user1' OR sender = 'user1' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN receiver = 'user1' THEN sender ELSE receiver END
```

which returns

[image]